# How is contradiction with definition of product of two sequences possible?

Tags: sequences-and-series, differential-geometry, cauchy-sequences

I read about Infinitesimal Differential Geometry in [this source, page 238-239](http://www.iam.fmph.uniba.sk/amuc/_vol-73/_no_2/_giordano/giordano.pdf) and I considered one example while I was reading. I was confused because in this example we have contradiction with definition of product of two sequences.

Example:

Let A is real number.

$A=[t]$

$t=sin(t)+o(t)$ $t$->$0$

$A \approx 0$

If $A \approx 0$ then $A^2 \approx 0$ but it's not true because in accordance with definition of product of two sequences we have:

$t^2=0+o(t)$ $t$->$0$

$A^2=[t]*[t]=[t*t]=0$

So, we get the contradiction.

How is contradiction with definition of product of two sequences possible?

Comment: The linked text defines $x(t)\sim y(t)$ iff $x(t)-y(t)\in o(t)$ and $x(t)\approx y(t)$ iff $x(t)-y(t)\in O(t)$, so $A\sim t\implies A^2\sim t^2$. Could you clarify with such notation what contradiction you perceive?

Comment: @J.G. Ok. In accordance with the linked text: $t-sin(t) \in o(t)$. $x=[t]$, $y=[sin(t)]$, $x=y$. Next I use $x$ and I obtain $x \approx 0$. Now $x^2$ must be positive because $x \approx 0$. But if we use $x(t)-y(t) \in o(t)$ we obtain $x^2=0$.

Comment: Those look like misuses of $=$ to me. Note $f\sim0$ iff $f\in o(t)$. If $x=t,\,y=\sin t$ (or do the square brackets mean something?) then $x\sim t,\,x^2\sim t^2$ so $x^2\approx0$. This doesn't contradict the fact that $x^2>0$ for small $t\ne0$.

Comment: @J.G. Square brackets mean equavalence class.

Comment: Ah, I see. So any real $A\ne0$ is $\approx$-equivalent to $t$, while $A^2$ is $\approx$-equivalent to $t^2$, because $A-t,\,A^2-t^2\in O(1)$.